# Run Python scripts without explicitly invoking `python`

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to run my python script without writing python func.py.
I've added to my script file #!/usr/bin/python2.7
did chmod +x func.py
when I try to run: ./func.py -p show -c all
the script works fine but if I try to take off the "flags" (-p , -c) or the "./" or ".py" it won't work.
taking flags off returns:

```
[root@pg66 tmp]# ./func.py  show  all
usage: func.py [-h] [-p PROCESS] [-c CLUSTER] [-t TYPE]
func.py: error: unrecognized arguments: show all
```

taking "./" & ".py" off returns:

```
[root@pg66 tmp]# func.py -p show -c all
-bash: func.py: command not found
```

edit: i have 3 flags -p -c -t , dont know where the -h came from. -t can be null so when i write -p show -c all it works.

Comment: First case, apparently you script requires some arguments & `show all` is not valid. Check your script to find out how to fix that. Second case, the `.py` can safely be removed in linux since file extensions don't matter much there. To remove `./` you need to put `func` somewhere in your PATH

Comment: This has nothing to do with taking the `python` off the command. You forgot the `-p` and the `-c`.

Comment: I run the commands from the same directory of my script, there is no way to run python script without specify the flags?

Comment: Those parameters are not positional, so they simply NEED the flag. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#introducing-positional-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the `chmod +* x`  in the location with the python file. This makes it easier for `linux/unix` After that you can run it by `./main.py` Assuming the file is named as `main.py`. You can also remove the `.py` extension then give the permission by `chmod +* x` and after that then just execute by `./main`. Another way to do this is simply going to the execution script of your terminal then add an alias for directly running the script just by typing the alias name

Comment: can you please explain the last sentence? I do want to run the script just by typing it's name without any ./ or .py .

Comment: place the script on your terminal home. Then on the ```bash.bashrc``` file of your terminal just put this ```alias script='python main.py'```  Then now you can run it by just typing ```script``` anywhere in your terminal. about the flags you will just add them after the ```script``` name. Eg: ```script -p ```. Try if it works especially the flags. I never did a script with flags. But i think it will work since the concept is the same